# Change in aggregate value in Tableau Dashboard

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop

Aggregate sum of Primary Key in a Tableau Graph changes upon introducing a drill-down dimension.
While *Distinct count of PrimaryKey* is **4979** and _Running Sum of Distinct count of PrimaryKey along with Table (Down) is also **4979**.

[image]

Upon introducing date/time field (*Open Date/time*) as a drill down dimension, the *Running Sum of Distinct count of PrimaryKey along Table (down)* increases to to **4982**.

[image]

What could be the possible reason for such anomaly ?

Answer (score 0):

A running sum is a table calculation that operates based on what is in the view. So 4249 + 733 = 4982. It's calculating exactly on what you introduced based by adding the date.

Now running sum distinct is more tricky. Check out this KB for a few options.
https://kb.tableau.com/articles/howto/calculating-a-running-count-distinct